# let $f(x) =\sin (4x-f(x))$ then $f'(0)=?$

Tags: derivatives

let $f(x) =\sin (4x-f(x))$ then $f'(0)=?$

---

My Try :

$$f'(x)=(4-f'(x))\cos(4x-f(x))$$

$$f'(0)=(4-f'(0))\cos(-f(0))$$

And :

$$f(0)=\sin(-f(0))$$

So :

$$f'(0)=(4-f'(0))\cos(-\sin (-f(0)))$$

Now what ?

Comment: $x=\sin(-x)$ does not have a lot of solutions.

Comment: CAS says: $  f'   \left( 0 \right) =2$

Answer (score 2):

we have $$f(0)=-\sin(f(0))$$ this equation hase only the solution $f(0)=0$ look at the equation $x=-\sin(x)$

Comment: why this equation has only the solution $f(0)=0$?

Comment: define the function $f(x)=x+\sin(x)$ and use calculus

Comment: we get $$f'(x)=1+\cos(x)\geq 0$$

Answer (score 2):

There *is* no function $f$ satisfying $f(x)=\sin(4x-f(x))$.  At least no differentiable function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Here's why:

As already pointed out, the equation $u=-\sin u$ has $u=0$ as its only solution.  (This is because setting $F(u)=u+\sin u$ implies $F'(u)=1+\cos u\ge0$ for all $u$, so $F$ is non-decreasing.) The same reasoning applies to the equation $u=\sin u$: It too has $u=0$ as its only solution.

Consider $x={\pi\over4}$.  We have

$$f\left(\pi\over4\right)=\sin\left(\pi-f\left(\pi\over4\right)\right)=\sin\left(f\left(\pi\over4\right)\right)$$

which implies $f\left(\pi\over4\right)=0$. But this in turn implies

$$f'\left(\pi\over4\right)=\left(4-f'\left(\pi\over4\right)\right)\cos\left(\pi-f\left(\pi\over4\right)\right)=\left(4-f'\left(\pi\over4\right)\right)\cos(\pi)=f'\left(\pi\over4\right)-4$$

which is impossible (unless $f'$ is undefined at $\pi\over4$).

If we drop the assumption of differentiability except at $x=0$, then $f(0)=0$ implies $f'(0)=(4-f'(0))\cos0=4-f'(0)$, which give $f'(0)=2$.  But this still assumes there *is* a function satisfying the functional equation $f(x)=\sin(4x-f(x))$ that is differentiable in some neighborhood of $x=0$.  In light of the above, it's not at all clear (to me, at least) that any such function exists. I'd like to see a proof, one way or the other. (A remark for anyone wanting to tackle the problem: setting $f(x)=g(4x)$ leads to the equivalent problem for the functional equation $g(x)=\sin(x-g(x))$, which might be slightly easier to work with.)